# How to get a fluid simulation to look like this?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

I have spent days messing around with the fluid simulation tool that comes with blender (v3.4) trying to achieve something that looks like [this](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/food/miscellaneous/water-splash-3d-model-e52057fa-53ba-4acd-a1fa-e354d681bd2b) (which was apparently done in blender).

Every YouTube tutorial where it follows a curve ends up looking like a blob, none of that nice 'splash' definition. Cranking up the sim detail doesn't seem to help.

I've seen nice tutorials with X-particles & C4D, but I cannot afford that... and I do not know how to reverse engineer it because they use features which mantaflow does not seem to have.

Any assistance would be very appreciated,

Comment: If you look at the third image, you can see the outliner, and there are two empties there. Camera003.target is probably just a target for a Track To constraint, but it may also act as a forcefield. Splash_3.001 is likely a forcefield. I cannot say how they were configured, but quite possibly Vortex or Turbulence. The description says this was made in Blender 2.83, which, if I remember correctly, was before Mantaflow was included in official releases. The fluidsim back then was a bit different.

Comment: According to the wiki, Mantaflow came with [Blender 2.82](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/Physics) so the linked reference was made with Manaflow. But the blend file for sale is just a static model (see reviews). So the screenshots don't help :-(